# creating zip file from a folder - in c++

Tags: c++, compression, zip

I want to create a program that , when executed, will compress a selected folder.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use boost, there's also [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/), along with [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html), which is a wrapper around zlib for managing zip files.

Comment: what are those exactly? can I use them in my c++ project?

Comment: Yes - minizip is in C, but I've used it for zipping and unzipping files from C++ - take a look at minizip.c in http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/unzip101e.zip

Answer (score 3):

In C++ probably the best option is to go to the Boost library. You can find it [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/home.html).